# What fitting algorithm does Mathematica use in NonlinearModelFit[]?

Tags: algorithm, wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting, nonlinear-functions, model-fitting

I need to know the algorithm(s) it uses, because I have to write my own program. Levenberg-Marquardt doesn't really do the same. Is there like a list of algorithms, from which Mathematica chooses what algorithm to use for a specific problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica 8.x can use the following algorithms for `NonLinearModelFit[]` for its `Method` option:

Possible settings for Method include `"ConjugateGradient"`, `"Gradient"`, `"LevenbergMarquardt"`, `"Newton"`, `"NMinimize"`, and `"QuasiNewton"`, with the default being `Automatic`.

See the documentation for additional options etc.

Note that `NonLinearFit[]` is obsolete; you should now use `FindFit[]` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. So are you telling me that it definitely is gonna use one of these algorithms? how would it choose between them? what's the criterion? I didn't really find enough info in Help.

Comment: Yes, the Automatic setting for this option chooses among these available algorithms. However, no additional info is given regarding how the choice is actually made.You can however select the algorithm you want to be used.

Comment: To select a specific method, use the option Method->"MethodName". For example, you can use:

NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, Method->"NMinimize"]